# Calling toCelsius method in java

Tags: java

This Question is from my programming class:

In the convertFToC method, change the second System.out.println statement so it produces a display such as
212.0 degrees Fahrenheit is 100.0 degrees Celsius
for an input of 212. If you are baffled by this instruction, here is a fuller description:
The first half of the output line ( 212 degrees Fahrenheit is ) is already written. The next item to be displayed is
the number of degrees celsius, which is being calculated and returned by the toCelsius method.
Remember (see Lecture 3 and preparation exercises) that the result of a return method can be used elsewhere in
a program by calling its name and providing the correct number and type of input parameters.
Call the toCelsius method within the System.out.println statement, sending it the data that it needs (the variable representing the degrees in fahrenheit).
Finish off the statement by concatenating the string " degrees Celsius" on the end.
This program should now compile. If you run it, it will convert one value from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

The code is below, can someone show me how to call the to toCelsius method. thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**Lab 4 COMP160 2020
 * Starting code*/
public class FahrenheitToCelsius{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    convertFToC();
    convertFToC();
    convertFToC();
    //Step 5;
  }

  /**gets input from user representing fahrenheit and displays celsius equivalent*/
  public static void convertFToC(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Fahrenhei temperature: ");
    double fahrenheit = scan.nextDouble(); //Step 2 - assign next double input from Scanner object
    System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " +  + " degrees Celsius"); //Step 4
  }

  /**calculates and returns the celsius equivalent of a double input parameter called fahr*/
  public static double toCelsius(double fahr){
    int BASE = 32;
    double CONVERSION_FACTOR = 9.0/ 5.0;
    double celsius = CONVERSION_FACTOR + BASE / fahr;//Step 3
    return celsius;
  }
}// end class
```

Comment: It's literally in the instructions: *"Remember (see Lecture 3 and preparation exercises) that the result of a return method can be used elsewhere in a program by calling its name and providing the correct number and type of input parameters."*

Comment: `System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + toCelsius(fahrenheit) + " degrees Celsius");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `toCelsius(fahrenheit)` between those two consecutive +s. And also correct the conversion formula in the method